# A series summation

Tags: improper-integrals, divergent-series, conjectures

How should I calculate the following expression?

\begin{equation}
T\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+(2\pi nT)^2}}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+\omega^2}}
\end{equation}

Since neither of the two terms converges, so what this expression really means is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(
T\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+(2\pi nT)^2}}-\int_{-2\pi NT}^{2\pi NT}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+\omega^2}}
\right)
\end{equation}

The answer to the above expression must be a function of $k/T$, say it is $f\left(\frac{k}{T}\right)$. I think this function $f$ has pretty good properties so that the following integral converges:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty dk\cdot k\cdot f\left(\frac{k}{T}\right)
\end{equation}

I suspect the final answer to the above integral is $\pi T^2\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ up to a factor of $2$.

Comment: For $k=1$ and $T\ge1$ we have $T-\dfrac{\ln\big(2\pi T\big)}\pi-\dfrac1{25}$

Comment: @Lucian, can you tell me how this is done? For $k\geqslant T$, I think the answer may be something like $\exp\left(-\frac{k^2}{T^2}\right)$